# TryReceive method on IMessageReceiver interface

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Please provide the following methods in `IMessageReceiver`:

```
bool TryReceive(out Message msg, TimeSpan timeout)
Task<bool> TryReceiveAsync(out Message msg, TimeSpan timeout)
```

So that we can use these like:

```
if (TryReceive(out Message msg, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. If you want to make a feature request, go to the library [repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues), not SO. StackOverflow is for questions and answers. Also, there will be no synchronous version as the entire library is about IO. Therefore it should be async.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a feature request, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a feature request for Azure Functions you can leave that feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions